# Infinite series in measure theory

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

This is a exercise of [Rudin's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0070542341).

Theorem 1.41. Let $\{E_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable sets in $(X,\eta,\mu)$ ($\eta$ is $\sigma$ algebra, $\mu$ is a positive measure),such that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)<\infty. \tag{1}$$

Then almost all $x\in X$ lie in at most finitely of sets $E_k$.

Proof(Rudin): If $A$ is the set of all $x$ which lie in infinitely many $E_k$, we have to prove that $\mu(A)=0$. Put
$$g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{E_k}(x), (x\in X).$$
For each $x$, each term in this series is $0$ or $1$. Hence $ x\in A$ if and only if $g(x)=\infty$. By theorem 1.27, the integral of $g$ over $X$ is equal to the sum in $(1)$. Thus $g\in L^1(\mu)$, and so $g(x)<\infty$ a.e. (almost everywhere) $\square$

Remark:
 $\mu(A_n)\to \mu(A)$ as $n\to \infty$ if $\displaystyle A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, $A_n\in{\eta}$,
$$A_1\supset A_2\supset A_3\supset \cdots,$$
and $\mu(A_1)$  is finite.

Exercise: Show that 
$$A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{E_k} \tag{2}$$

in Theorem 1.41, and hence prove the theorem without any reference to integration.

Proof: If $A$ is the set of all $x$ which lie in infinitely many $E_k$, we have to prove that $\mu(A)=0$.

We first show that (2) is true. Indeed, $x\in A$ if and only if for each $r\in \mathbb{N}$, exists $r<k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in E_k$, thus 
$$x\in \left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}{E_k}\right)\bigcap \left(\bigcup_{k=2}^{\infty}{E_k}\right)\bigcap \cdots  $$

and $(2)$ holds.

Now, show that $\mu(A)=0$. If $\displaystyle A_n=\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k $,  then

$$\mu(A_1)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)<\infty$$
thus $\mu(A_1)$ is finite.

Now,
$$\mu(A_n)\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu(E_k) \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}\mu(A_n)\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)=0$$

thus, by the remark $\mu(A_n)\to 0=\mu(A)$, this concludes the proof. $\square$

Is correct?

How prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu(E_k)=0$? (Intuitively is true).

Thanks you all.

Comment: For the last question, remember the Cauchy criterion for convergent series. A series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if for each $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that for $m\geq n\geq N$ we have $ \left|\sum_{k=n}^m a_k \right| <\varepsilon$. Let $m\to \infty $ and you have $\left|\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \right| <\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. This is exactly the definition of the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k=0 $.

Comment: @Benjamin; You are right. I've edited.

Comment: @Dimitrios; Thank you.

Comment: @Dimitris  I have two questions  . Can you please help  1 . Is Set A Borel Set?  2 . Is { $ E_k $} subbasis for a topology on X and also please tell what is that topology ?